# Rails infinite loop while updating other record's value during `before_save`

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this model in Rails (trimmed to the relevant parts)

```
class Session < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  before_save :invalidate_existing_sessions


  def invalidate_existing_sessions
    Session.where(user_id: user.id, current: true).each { |sess| sess.update_attributes(current: false) }
  end
end
```

However, when a record is created and about to be saved, the server goes into an infinite loop.

Here are the server logs

```
Processing by V1::SessionsController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"email"=>"user@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "session"=>{}}
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["email", "user@example.com"]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Session Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "sessions".* FROM "sessions" WHERE "sessions"."user_id" = $1 AND "sessions"."current" = $2  [["user_id", 1
], ["current", true]]
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "sessions".* FROM "sessions" WHERE "sessions"."user_id" = $1 AND "sessions"."current" = $2  [["user_id", 1], ["cu
rrent", true]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "sessions".* FROM "sessions" WHERE "sessions"."user_id" = $1 AND "sessions"."current" = $2  [["user_id", 1], ["cu
rrent", true]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "sessions".* FROM "sessions" WHERE "sessions"."user_id" = $1 AND "sessions"."current" = $2  [["user_id", 1], ["cu
rrent", true]]
```

A bit later, this is what the log turns into

```
  app/models/session.rb:12:in `invalidate_existing_sessions'
  app/models/session.rb:12:in `block in invalidate_existing_sessions'
  app/models/session.rb:12:in `invalidate_existing_sessions'
  app/models/session.rb:12:in `block in invalidate_existing_sessions'
  app/models/session.rb:12:in `invalidate_existing_sessions'
  app/models/session.rb:12:in `block in invalidate_existing_sessions'
  app/models/session.rb:12:in `invalidate_existing_sessions'
```

Any ideas? I'm using Rails 5 alpha.

Comment: `before_save` is calling **save** action using `update_attributes`. Which is recursively calling before_save. That's the reason for infinite loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though all of the above answers worked for me, this is what I found  simplest and I ended up using.

```
def invalidate_existing_sessions
  Session.where(user_id: user.id, current: true).each { |sess| sess.update_column(:current, false) }
end
```

Turns out `update_column` doesn't call any callbacks, but as an disadvantage it doesn't update `updated_at` if you're using timestamps in your model.

Answer (score 2):

It's because your `before_save` method does this...

```
sess.update_attributes(current: false)
```

Since update_attributes calls `before_save` you are (as you say) in an infinite loop.

So you need to skip the callbacks

```
class Session < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :skip_callbacks
  before_save :invalidate_existing_sessions, unless: :skip_callbacks

  def invalidate_existing_sessions
    Session.where(user_id: user.id, current: true).each do |sess|  
      sess.skip_callbacks = true
      sess.update_attributes(current: false) 
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

You're running `update_attributes` in `before_save`, that means you're saving before save. That's why it goes into an infinite loop.

Comment: This is still going to loop indefinitely. The condition is true for the initial record, the condition is also true just before you try to save the old record, and  old record is not being saved because of interminable call backs.